# How to put thousand separators in kendo pie chart labels?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo pie chart and I want to display some dollar amount with thousand separators. Currently I am getting result as "$4312341.87" but I want it like this: "$4,312,341.87".

I also want to reduce the size of the pie chart without reducing the size of a complete div.

Here is my code,

```
            $("#pie-chart").kendoChart({
            legend: {
                visible: false
            },
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "myService",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                }
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "pie",
                startAngle: 0,
                labels: {
                    /
                    template: "$${value}",
                    //template: '#= kendo.toString(value, "c") #', 
                    format: "c",
                    visible: true,
                    font: "1.1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;",
                    background: "transparent",
                    margin: 0,
                    padding: 0
                }
            },
            seriesColors: ["#0066FF", "#FF9900", "#CC0000", "#004D71"],
            series: [
                {
                    field: "current"
                }],
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "$${value}"
            },
            chartArea: { margin: 1 },
            plotArea: { margin: 1 }
        });
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem about using `template: '#= kendo.toString(value, "c") #'` as you have commented in your code?

Comment: Its not returning the correct result.

Comment: Check this http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/iMeB

Comment: I tried exactly like you said. But it did not work. If possible, can you provide me an example with some remote data.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is remote or local. The difference it's likely to be that you are sending the data as string and not as number. Is it possible? Can you show an example of the JSON received with your data?

Comment: Yes. The data received is like this: [{"Asia": 5000, "Europe": 10000, "Australia": 3000, "North America": 8500}]

Comment: Either your code is not complete or that is not all the data. I cannot see how your code is able to display a pie-chart with that data.